# Exit Do look in nested For loop break all loops

Tags: vba, nested-loops, exit, do-loops

I am new to VBA and getting stuck with a small piece of code which I think I am missing something very easy. I have a column of 0,1 and 2 and trying to calculate the transitions from 0 to 2 and then back to 0 when 0 appears for consecutively atleast A times and 2 appears for consecutive B times. After putting the For and IF loops, I want to exit the Do loop so that it does not get over counted. However putting the Exit Do shows compilation error and shows all the End If and Next statement as an error. I am totally confused why that is happening and any help on it will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
For L = M To lastrow - A
temp = 0
For L1 = L To L + A
    temp = temp + Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH" & L1)
Next L1
If temp = 0 Then
    N = L + A: A_start = N: x_start = x_start + 1
    For N1 = N To 50 'lastrow - B
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH" & N1) = 2 Then
            temp1 = 0
            For I1 = N1 To N1 + B
                temp1 = temp1 + Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH" & I1)
            Next I1
            Do While temp1 = 2 * B
                Count = Count + 1: M = I1: B_start = I1: x_Stop = x_Stop + 1
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AN2") = Count
            Exit Do
        End If
    Next N1
End If
Next L
```

Comment: The Do While needs to have a Loop Statement.  It would be placed on the line after Exit Do.  Or perhaps in place of the Exit Do.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Thank you for your comment. Initially I was trying with If condition. However, then I came to know that there is no Break statement in If loop. Thus, I tried with Do loop. Could you please suggest how the code should look like according to you? Thank you

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement)?

Comment: You can use goto and a label to leave a loop.

Comment: Yes @NicholasHunter. But am not sure how can I re-frame the code. This is the only way I can think about which is not working for sure

Comment: @Xypron Thanks for your suggestion. But, in the code,if condition met, it will increase the count by 1 and then again be in the loop for the rest of the sections. Will go to be used for that?

Comment: If you want your code to compile, you need to change Exit Do to Loop as @BrianMStafford already suggested. I am afraid I do not understand what you're trying to do so I can not advise further.

Comment: I really appreciate both of your comment @NicholasHunter. However, I am getting difficulty with the structure of the loop then. If any of you can edit the small segment of the code where it needs to be changed, that would be very helpful. Thanks for your time